# Sort Firestore Collection using useCollection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm trying to set up this collection using firestore & react-firebase-hooks:

```
const [channelMessages, loading] = useCollection(
    channelId && collection(getFirestore(app), "channels", channelId, "messages"),
    orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
);
```

This however does not do any sorting. When looking at:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

I do see that you can sort using the firestore query.

How do i implement this into the useCollection hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what `channelId &&` is supposed to do in your code, but ignoring that, you can use a sorted collection with:

```
useCollection(
  query(
    collection(getFirestore(app), "channels", channelId, "messages"),
    orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
  )
);
```